# iTextSharp Image placement performance

Tags: image, pdf, itext

I have about 2000 images at 8 X 11 inches, they range in size from 10 k to 1 meg With the below code I loop through a directory and insert the TIFF files onto a new page within a new PDF file that I create. this process takes about 10 mins I'm running this on a win 8 server with 12 gigs of ram and 2 X 2.13 GHz processors (Noting else running ) I like to see if I can get the time down.

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing this. It works just a little slow. It just might be the fasted way but was wondering if anyone might have a better way of doing the above process.

```
using (ouput = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    using (doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER))
    {
        using (writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ouput))
        {
            doc.Open();

            foreach (string dir in Directory.GetFiles(TIFFiles,"*.tif", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            {

                Console.Write("\rMerging : {0}....", Path.GetFileName(dir));
                iTextSharp.text.Image TIFF = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(dir);
                TIFF.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);                               
                writer.DirectContent.AddImage(TIFF);
                doc.NewPage();

            }

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("End Time: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));

            doc.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One way that _might_ work would be to create a bunch of smaller individual PDFs that have maybe a couple of dozen images in them. This task could be paralyzed and you could then stitch those PDFs together. You _might_ also eke out a couple of seconds by switching from `Directory.GetFiles` to `Directory.EnumerateFiles`.

Comment: okay I see where you going with that some logic change might me in  order here  let me try that why not.. also I try Directory.EnumerateFile thanks your input!! I'll let you know what I find out.. thanks again Chris.

Comment: Ideally you'd have (at least) 4 results: 1. all images with `Directory.GetFiles` 2. all images with `Directory.EnumerateFiles` 3. in parallel, with `Directory.GetFiles` 4. in parallel, with `Directory.EnumerateFiles`. Even more results, because you can choose how big your batches are: per 10, per 50, per 100,... could all be different, and somewhere you can maybe find a "magic number". It would be interesting to see the results.